# When does Magento use sessions and when cookies?

Tags: magento-1, session, cookie

I know Magento has following core functions for session and cookie handling:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
```

When does Magento set Cookies and when PHP Sessions? What are the use cases?

I'm a bit confused, because I know Magento stores the cart information in `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` and the status of the user in `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')`. But the checkout session doesn't seem to be a session, but a cookie instead. Because when I close the browser and re-open the page the items are still in the cart.

Does that mean, that the `checkout/session`model sets cookies and not the global `$_SESSION` variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, that means that sessions are persisted with a cookie, which contains the ID of the session. The only alternative in PHP is a URL parameter like `?SID=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` where `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` is the session ID.

In Short, session **data** are stored on the server but since HTTP is stateless, a cookie or parameter with the session **id** is necessary to identify the right session.

Magento sets two session cookies, `adminhtml` for the backend and `frontend` for the frontend. Session models like `'checkout/session'` store their data in a "namespace", i.e. `$_SESSION['checkout']`.

Session-unrelated cookies that Magento sets, are for example the `store` cookie that remembers, which store view you currently browse.

Answer (score 0):

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` Saves all data you selected in `Flats` tables example. `sales_flat_quote` `sales_flat_quote_address` and more.

What is this: every customer at its first visit receives a `quote_id` which is unique and a relation with data in others `quote` tables and it is persistent that's why you always can see your Cart. This data everytime you change cart, data and something in your checkout form  before you finish an order. After you finish your order all quote data is got and saved in `order` tables ep. `sales_order_items` and your quote data gets a disable status. This happens everytime you make and order.

`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')` has your customer data when you are logged.

---

I hope this makes sense for you. This can be easier to explain by talking. The way than magento manage his data is complex and really good distributed but once you understand how data is manage and how to manipulate it. You did it Esasy cake magento.

---

UPDATE

this is the way to get `quote_id` by session

```
   $session        = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
   $quote_id       = $session->getQuoteId();
```

Comment: So is this ``quote_id`` saved in a session or cookie?

Comment: in Session. Cookies are a mechanism for storing data in the remote browser and thus tracking or identifying return users.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand. The session does expire when I close the browser. But how does Magento still remember the ``quote_id`` and thereby cart items when re-opening the browser?

Comment: Your session stores your IP and when you come back Magento use it to get your `quote_id` and Magic you can see your Cart again. Logged and not logged user have a `quote_id` Quote Data doesn't expire

Comment: Visit in your admin backend. Reports->Carts->Abandoned Carts And check it

Comment: Something than helps me to understand all this was. Open your Magento Database and go to Tables.. `Sales_Flat` and `Sales_Order` and test. Add a product to cart, insert data in checkout forms as not logged and check how data stores in data tables first Sales_Flat and after you finish order Sales_Order

Comment: The better way to understand magento is test and see how it works :)

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking dumb questions, but you're saying ``Your session stores your IP ``. But Sessions are only valid until the browser is being closed, correct? Then the session is being destroyed, correct?

Comment: Don't care about you are asking. In PHP session variables are destroyed when you close Browser. In Magento is the same it use php session but `Session Variables` in Magento are filled from `Quote and Customer Tables` in the moment you visit the site and it reconize you have a `quote_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again :) So if I get you right you say that all the quote and customer data are being retrieved from the ``quote_id``. But the ``quote_id`` is stored in the PHP session. My questions remains. If it is in the PHP session and not a cookie, why is it still there when I close the browser?

Comment: When you close browser data is already store in `Quote Tables` referenced by `quote_id` .. when come back. And Magento identify than your quote exist, data is filled in case it's not. Magento creates a new quote for you.

Comment: Yes its clear that the data is stored in ``Quote Tables`` and referenced by ``quote_id`` for returning customers. But where does the system look for ``quote_id``? You say ``quote_id`` is in the PHP session. I wonder - how can it be in the PHP session if my cart data is still accessible after re-opening the browser (since the PHP session is lost).

Comment: I mean ``quote_id`` must be stored somewhere to retrieve the cart details. WHERE? I do assume it's stored in the frontend cookie ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21569/discussion-between-duarte-and-rouzbeh).

Comment: Yes, it happens for not logged customers.

Comment: Ok, check this. 
**1)Not logged:**
You added 3 products to Cart then data is saved in `sales_flat_quote` if you remove cookies and cache. Your data is lost and your Cart will be empty. So not logged users their token is based in cookies and cache.
**2)Logged:**
Same 3 products in Cart And you clear Browser cookies and cache. you get logout but when you log in 3 products still there.

All this magic is managed by `quote`

Comment: So that was exactly my problem. I assumed ``Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')`` refers to PHP Sessions (as the name suggests) and would not set Cookies.